# Exchange 2003 Cross-Forest Exchange 2010 MailContacts Migration

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, migration, exchange-2010, active-directory

I need some pointers in how to migrate 2500 mailcontacts and 1000 distributiongroups from Exchange 2003 to 2010 in an Cross-Forest oraganization.

It seems no one in our beloved skynetz(google) has done this before.. so im pretty much clueless after a week of powershelling without any luck.

First i tought i could use ADMT, but ADMT doesnt like contacts or distribution groups.

Allright, so.. hmm exhange management console and powershell?

When you create a new-mailcontact and points it to its ou in the new domain its not sure it gets the same common name for some reason. Thus screwing the group memberships later on.
Sure i could do a search for the correct email address for each member of a group to add the corect distinguished name to the group but then.. it would take days to process all the contacts and groups.

Is there some other way to migrate mailcontacts and distribution groups keeping the membershipstatus?

Answer (score 1):

I have just completed this for a large org.  DL i did through a powershell script to copy email addresses from one forest to another.  With contacts i exported them with csvde and painfully put them back into groups. This was due to the org OU structure changing.  Let me know how you go.

Comment: Good way to do it, and welcome to Server Fault!